# Проблема с Seekbar

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь сделать аудио книгу. Я смог воспроизвести из папки треки но не могу поставить SeekBar. Еще мне нужно вывести имя проигрываемого трека.

```
package simolapps.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    TextView tb_title;

    int  pos  = 0;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final String[] listContent = { "0000", "0001",  };
    private final int[] resID = { R.raw.a0001, R.raw.a0000,  };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        // Initializing variables
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);




            }
        });

        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mSeekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());


        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });



    }


    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            mp.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }


    public void play (View view) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop (View view) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
// Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);// create's

        mp.start(); // starting mediaplayer
        startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }


    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mp.pause();

            mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="play" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="stop" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mSeekBar"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="1000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/tb_title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вы и не пыталсь добавить `SeekBar`. Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: То что  я добавлял не работало и я его удалил... Я пробовал несколько  вариантов, безрезультатно ....(

Comment: ...и теперь вы хоиите, чтобы кто-то написал это вместо вас? Так не пойдет, показывайте, что пробовали, и что именно не получалось, или не получите ответа тут.

Comment: Отдельно составить вопрос? или есть вариант изменить код который поставил выше?@katso

Comment: вы вроде бы можете отредактировать вопрос. Не помню, есть ли ограничение по мин. репутации

Comment: Я это взял с этого урока http://devcolibri.com/257  @katso

Comment: ужасный урок. Костыли одни. У SeekBar есть специальный колбек на изменение прогресса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У `SeekBar` есть свой собственный `Listener` на изменение прогресса. Ненадо использовать костыли с `onTouch`

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Comment: я не понимаю что я не так делаю ... Но меня выкидывает ( @metalurgus

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, откуда выкидывает? Приложение закрывается с ошибкой? Если да, то показывайте стактрейс ошибки

Comment: да, приложение закрывается с ошибкой, может я просто не так его туда прописал ...

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров показывайте стактрейс ошибки

Comment: Process: simolapps.myapplication, PID: 8867
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, Точно не туда вставили.

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, надо вместо `mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                seekChange(v);
                return false;
            }
        });`

Comment: на телефоне ошибку выдает а на эмуляторе seekbar не двигается @metalurgus

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, значит вы что-то сделали неправильно. Никто кроме вас не знает, что именно потому, что только вы видите свой код.

Comment: могу показать свой код )) ... Я уже столько с этим мучаюсь ... для ios тоже сделал кое как ... Теперь все из за этого тянется

Comment: взгляни пожалуйста еще раз... я изменил в вопросе код и добавил xml layaut   @metalurgus

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, посмотрите точно, на какой строке, и какая ошибка возникает. `java.lang.NullPointerException`, который вы привели раньше не может возникать на этой строке.

Comment: 06-22 16:35:04.342 15089-15089/simolapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration without a valid mediaplayer
06-22 16:35:04.342 15089-15089/simolapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
06-22 16:35:04.364 15089-15089/simolapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Comment: А это выходит при нажатии на playlist для воспроизведения 06-22 16:35:24.453 15089-15089/simolapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-22 16:35:24.460 15089-15089/simolapps.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set   @metalurgus

Answer (score 0):

```
package simolapps.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    // variable declaration
    private ListView mainList;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;
    TextView tb_title;

    int  pos  = 0;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final String[] listContent = { "0000", "0001",  };
    private final int[] resID = { R.raw.a0001, R.raw.a0000,  };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        // Initializing variables
    }

    private void initViews() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);



            }
        });



    }


    private void seekChange(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
            mp.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }
    }


    public void play (View view) {
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
        } else {
            mp.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop (View view) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {
// Play song
        mp.reset();// stops any current playing song
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resID[songIndex]);




        mp.start();


        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mSeekBar);
        mSeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());


        mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }


        });



        startPlayProgressUpdater();
    }


    public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }else{
            mp.pause();

            mSeekBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: Решено, я код поместил туда куда нужно

Comment: не понятно только, почему вы скопировали мой ответ, и отметили его как правильный?

Comment: @metalurgus проблема вообще не в том оказалось что я с того урока поставил код ... он тоже работает .... Я поставил его тогда не туда... А тут я все правильно поставил и все работает теперь